# C# FTP connections and timeouts

Tags: c#, ftp

I will try to explain everything first without placing my codes. Maybe I made/missed some scenarios which caused the problem.

I have an app, it connects to an FTP folder, retrieves any file from a specific folder, downloads the file(s), and processes it, period.  The thing is, I want these to keep on repeating after a specific time (batch, using timer.interval).

At first pass (folder has a valid file), app runs smoothly... downloads the file(s) in the folder, processes the file(s) but after a few hours and when no file(s) is/are present, app would shout "The Operation has timed out" (i've logged all exceptions errors to a different text file).  Placing a new (and valid) file to the folder would still give the Operation Timed out error when I do a "WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse" which continues forever.

Would like to ask anyone who experienced this?  What aspect/areas do I need to consider to be covered?  Thanks in advance for your replies...

Frederick

Comment: Do you close the connection after you've done a list (no files available) or downloaded all the files?  So as I understand it, you connect and check/download then the program exits and is restarted at some time interval by the batch? What happens when it time's out?  Do you get an exception?

Comment: "What happens when it time's out? Do you get an exception? " - when there is no file in the folder? yes, i've enclosed it inside try catch and gets logged to text file.... after 3 or 4 iterations, the error then becomes 'Operation has timed out' and goes on forever.  Got an idea that probably connection (before exception) was not properly closed...